# iPhone UIWebView - How do you set the zoom level and position?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I'm displaying a series of tiled images in a UIWebView and would like to programmatically set the UIWebview's initial zoom and view location.

How does one go about doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: this answer is from 2009. Please see one of the better solutions for a more civilized age.

---

Programmatic scrolling of UIScrollView is now a solved problem. I have a detailed discussion of how (and why) UIScrollView zooming works, an example project and ZoomScrollView class that encapsulates the required zooming magic at [github.com/andreyvit/ScrollingMadness/](http://github.com/andreyvit/ScrollingMadness/).

So probably you should put your images inside UIScrollView like Andy advised.

Comment: You are totally right.  In the time from when I asked my question to now I ended up doing it in a manner similar (not as complete) to your "ScrollingMadness".

Comment: So, how does this help scroll an UIWebView and set a zoom level?

Comment: @BillCheswick Perhaps time to delete this answer? It's the accepted one, though, so not sure if I'm supposed to do that or not.

Answer (score 8):

Set attribute scalesPageToFit of UIWebView to YES. Then the webpage is scaled to fit and the user can zoom in and zoom out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
for (UIView *subview in webView.subviews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        ((UIScrollView *)subview).bounces = NO;
        [((UIScrollView *)subview) setZoomScale:10.5f animated:YES];
    }
}
```

It may be the solution to your problem.

Comment: why not use   webView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5; OR  
                      webView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 20.0; etc

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there's a documented way to do what you want.  An alternative that only half solves your problem is using a UIScrollView.  You could put UIImageViews inside your UIScrollView and then scroll to any position in the scroll view.  This does not allow you to programmatically zoom the view though.  If it's something you think should be added to the SDK file a radar: http://bugreport.apple.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
for (id subview in webview)
    if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])  {
         ((UIScrollView *)subview).bounces = NO;
     }
}
```

try using this scrollview.