# How to zoom web view programmatically?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

Is any idea, how to set zoom level of webview by programming ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this thread solves your problem? [iPhone UIWebView - How do you set the zoom level and position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674368/iphone-uiwebview-how-do-you-set-the-zoom-level-and-position)

alex