# UiWebView reset zoom programmatically

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, zooming

Is there a way to zoom out or reset a UiWebView programmatically ? if yes how ?

Answer (score 3):

i think you should be able to manipulate the viewport using the safari meta tags

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008193-SW6

For example, to set the viewport width to the width of the device, add this to your HTML file:

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width">
```

To set the initial scale to 1.0, add this to your HTML file:

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "initial-scale = 1.0">
```

To set the initial scale and to turn off user scaling, add this to your HTML file:

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "initial-scale = 2.3, user-scalable = no">
```

Comment: Ya correct. But how to control it after the view is displayed and zoomed by the user ?

Comment: The documentation states that by setting user-scalable to "no" will prevent the user from zooming at all?

Maybe I am not understanding the question?

Answer (score 0):

It's not directly supported, but this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674368/iphone-uiwebview-how-do-you-set-the-zoom-level-and-position) has a workaround/solution.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to reset the user scale to 1.0, at least on iOS 4.2 you can toggle `scalesPageToFit`:

```
webView.scalesPageToFit = NO;
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```