# UIWebView set initial zoom scale programmatically when loading an external website?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, zooming

What I want to do is set the initial zoom scale [and in some cases, content offset, but that is less important] for an external website.  But after the app initially sets the zoom and offset, the user should be able to change them, and the app should not interfere.

Some related information is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418547/uiwebview-reset-zoom-programatically), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674368/iphone-uiwebview-how-do-you-set-the-zoom-level-and-position), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305955/iphone-uiwebview-programatic-zoom).  But as far as I can tell, none of does what I want.

The meta setting approach looks promising -- but how would I set it when I don't control the html content that will be loaded?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this for setting the initial zoom level -

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document. body.style.zoom = 5.0;"];
```

Also dont forget to set `scalesPageToFit` to NO and you're done.

> If you set this to YES, the webpage is scaled to fit and the user can zoom in and zoom out. If NO, user zooming is disabled. The default value is NO.

Comment: I put this into webViewDidFinishLoad, and it works great, thanks!  But I do want to allow the user to change my initial zoom.  I do NOT want the page to be scaled to fit [which it isn't] -- but user zooming is disable.

Comment: Thanks a lot , This is the easiest solution i found.. I wish i could give 100 vote ups. ;)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to set initial zoom for your web view and then your web view can scaleable. You can try to add meta tag into the head tag of your HTML string at webViewDidFinishLoad protocol method. You can change 'initial-scale', 'minimum-scale'and 'maximum-scale' to adapt to your required. Looks like this:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSString* js =
    @"var meta = document.createElement('meta'); " \
    "meta.setAttribute( 'name', 'viewport' ); " \
    "meta.setAttribute( 'content', 'width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=10.0 user-scalable = yes' ); " \
    "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta)";
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: js];
}
```

Comment: Thanks  I know about this tags but I don't know how to implement. You save my day.

Answer (score 2):

Why not:

```
   [self.webView.scrollView setZoomScale:2.0 animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

[best one found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8143786/3577656) try adding meta tag in your html page,in your  tag.It gets repaired in a eye blink. 
Try the [apple link](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html) and select the suitable meta tag for you.

Answer (score 0):

if you are loading html and javascriptin uiwebview then in viewport set user-scalable=1.0.